# Oracle Partitioning

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, partitioning

I have 1 table which contain 8 subtables. Each subtable contains another 3 to 5 subtables. Now my question is that is it possible to partition tables by hierarchy? That means i like to keep all the tables info in one table and then create partitioning on them.

Comment: "Subtable"? Do they all have the same logical structure?

Comment: As David alluded to, your use of the word "subtable" is ambiguous and is throwing ORA-00960s in our heads.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Oracle allows us to define partitions within partitions: it is called [subpartitioning](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10743/partconc.htm#i449863).

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:
1. First Partition the main table and proceed with the sub partition.

1. Make partition and sub partition in a single query.

Note:
use DBMS_REDEFINITION  and RANGE partitioning